# A Way To Simplify this JavaScript File? jQuery show/hide?

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have 4 divs, and 4 corresponding buttons. When you click button1, it shows div 1 and hides all the others. so and and so forth. instead of having to list all of the divs to hide, can I just have a 'hide all other divs' sort of string? Not hide every div on the page, but hide every #div(number).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var h1 = $("#div56").height();
var h2 = $("#div54").height();
var h3 = $("#div47").height();
var h4 = $("#div45").height();
$("#div56,#div54,#div47,#div45").height(… h2, h3, h4));
$("#div54,#div47,#div45").hide();
});

$("#lnk56").live('click', function() {
$("#div56").show();
$("#div54,#div47,#div45").hide();
});
$("#lnk54").live('click', function() {
$("#div54").show();
$("#div56,#div47,#div45").hide();
});
$("#lnk47").live('click', function() {
$("#div47").show();
$("#div56,#div54,#div45").hide();
});
$("#lnk45").live('click', function() {
$("#div45").show();
$("#div56,#div54,#div47").hide();
});
```

This is the corresponding HTML/PHP:

```
    <div class="grid_5">

        <?php query_posts( 'post_type=credits&showposts=99999'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post">

<div class="buttons">
            <a id="lnk<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="#"><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5></a>
</div><!--/buttons-->

<?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

        </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div><!--/grid_5-->

<div class="grid_7">
        <div class="scrollbox">
        <div id="divParent">

                <?php query_posts( 'post_type=credits'); ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="info" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                <?php the_content(); ?>

        </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


                </div><!--/divParent-->
       </div>
        </div><!--/grid_7-->
```

Comment: this would be easier if you could provide the HTML

Comment: Can you add a class to all the DIVs you want to hide and show?  That way, you could hide all divs with that class and then show the one that should be displayed.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should use .on() instead of .live(). It is known to have pretty bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class (say "divGroup") on all these divs and then do something like this:

```
function() {
    $("div.divGroup").hide();
    this.show();
}

$("#lnk56").live('click', showIt());
... repeat for all divs ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide by using a class and to make it dynamic, you can use data-* attributes to retrieve the correct Id from the button and show the corresponding div. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V9ZZy/

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(){
       var id = $(this).attr('data-btn-id');
       $(".myDivs").hide();
       $("#div" + id).show();
});


    <div id="div1" class="myDivs">Hello 1</div>
<button id="btn1" data-btn-id="1">Btn 1</button>

<div id="div2" class="myDivs">Hello 2</div>
<button id="btn2"  data-btn-id="2">Btn 2</button>

<div id="div3" class="myDivs">Hello 3</div>
<button id="btn3"  data-btn-id="3">Btn 3</button>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some regex to listen to all the links

```
$('body').on("click", "[id^="lnk"]", function(event){
   $(this).parent().show();
});
```

Comment: This would work to show the divs only if the buttons were inside of them, but would not work to hide the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button[id^="lnk"]').on('click', function () {
        $('div[id^="div"]').hide();
        var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(3);
        $('#div' + id).show();
    });
});
```

This will effect all buttons with id's that start with `lnk`. However since we don't have the html to work with I will assume that is the intention.